# Pass value from Astro file to Preact component

Tags: preact, astrojs

I just started with Astro framework, and I must say that it is quite confusing, with code that only runs build time

Anyway, here is my Astro file

```
---
   const x = signal(0);
---

<input id="x" type="checkbox">
<script is:inline>
    document.getElementById('x').addEventListener('change', e => {
       x.value = e.target.value ? 1 : 0;
    });
</script>
<MyPreactComponent count={x} />
```

Then in my preact component

```
export default function MyPreactComponent({count}) {
    return (
       <span>{count}</span>
    )
}
```

Now for some reason only the initial value is displayed. Maybe some parts of this code ran build time and the other runtime, I'm lost :( Any suggestions?

Comment: Anything in the component script (the part between the two `---`) exists only in the server and is run at build time (or on the server if using SSR), as well as anything in JSX-like expressions in the HTML. Check out the [islands](https://docs.astro.build/en/concepts/islands/) and [framework components](https://docs.astro.build/en/core-concepts/framework-components/) docs. Or check out the [final section of the Astro tutorial](https://docs.astro.build/en/tutorial/6-islands/) which briefly covers the usage of islands.